# How create a shooting system in SceneKit

Tags: scenekit

I would like to know how to make a shooting system with a weapon with SceneKit please? Especially taking into account the player's rotation...

I can position the projectile with

bullet.simdWorldPosition = player.simdWorldPosition

I know how to applyforce with

bullet.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3(0,0,-20), asImpulse: true)

But as soon as I move the camera or the player's rotation naturally it no longer works at all...

Thanks

Comment: Hi @jeremyjoron, I did some shooting system one in one of my scenekit/arkit apps. Can you provide me your project or post some of the code-blocks you use fot the shooting system, and some of the scene configuration, I can then take a look at it.